# JIRA - How to create a new series of key value for a issue type?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Be default in jira, any issue type will have the same series of Issue ID. for example i create a defect id will be `<project name>:<jira ID>`, and if i create a new user story jira iD will be in the same sequence ?

How can i do a custom jira id for a new issue type.

Comment: not clear what you actually trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are asking is you want issue types to have their own sequence of ID's. This is not possible with out of the box JIRA.

You could look to do some sort of your own custom field that you have auto-increment based off some criteria to give you a secondary ID but I wouldn't recommend it.